# mvc 2.0 validation

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

I am use DataAnnotations validation, it work perfectly but when I validate empty text box field I have error

> The value '' is invalid

how can I customize this error?

p.s.
error shows only when clients script are off

Comment: Do you want to change the error message?

Comment: yes, i want to make custom error

Comment: it looks like a bug
http://forums.asp.net/t/1529205.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the error message in your DataAnnotations attribute.  For example, take the following view model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When that gets validated, it will give "You must enter a name" as the error message to the user.